# Least cost path plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, dijkstra

For my Bachelor's thesis I try to calculate the least cost path inside a polygon. The Least cost path plugin is good for it https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/leastcostpath/#plugin-versions. But I need to understand how it works.

I understood that I need to rasterize the vector layer and then apply the plugin. The plugin uses  Dijkstra's algorithm with Manhattan distance (like A* algorithm) to find a least cost path. And I think it means that this plugin uses a graph. But I don't understand how it calculates weights of edges with color and distance.

Usually for the shortest path the edge weight is a Pythagorean distance between the start and end points, calculated from the xy coordinates. But Least cost path plugin also uses pixel color to find the least cost path. And I don't understand how it works.

Could anybody help me to understand?

Comment: The good thing about open source is that you can get the code and see exactly how it works: https://github.com/Gooong/LeastCostPath/blob/master/dijkstra_algorithm.py is able to be read openly. If you're writing a thesis you should be able to discern how it works by yourself... homework questions are seldom answered on this site and a thesis is far more than homework, put in some of your own effort and if there's a bit you truly don't understand post the section of code you're having difficulty understanding as a new question.

Comment: Color is just a visualization and does not play any role. What is important is the pixel value (cost) of the raster. Each pixel has a value: the larger it is, the more cost you accumulate to travel through this pixel. So the algorithm tries to avoid pixels with larger pixel values (cost). See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/459204/88814

Comment: @Babel, thank you!