Computing bilateral travel times between Belgian municipality per travel mode in 1896
I'm conducting an historical study concerning the impact of the first railways on structural transformation of the 19th century Belgian economy (i.e. industrial revolution).
A part of my analysis is looking at the drastic decrease in travel times between walking to every location (municipality in Belgium) and talking the train.
I have already performed some preliminary steps and I do believe I have all the ingredients to create a commuting matrix containing travel times between each municipality in Belgium. The only problem is that I don't know how to combine them.
By now I have:

a vector later with points for every Belgian municipality
a distance matrix between every Belgian municipality
cost surface areas (.tif files) for every municipality for the walk mode and all (walking + rail) mode
(Note that the travel speeds in the cost surface areas are calibrated based on the time, in minutes, needed to travel one kilometer for each mode. This is because the procedure minimizes the aggregated travel cost across the cost surface area to determine inter-municipal travel times.)

How do I use those CSA's to estimate the bilateral minimal travel cost (in minutes) to reach other municipalities, conditional on the available transport network by mode and export the results to a .CSV file?

Use a Least cost path anlaysis based on the two CSA, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/459200/88814 , https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/474196/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439618/88814 - like from municipality A to all other (B to Z) for 1) walking, 2) walking+rail. You get a cost (traveltime/distance, based on what you have) for each connection. If you had a network (walking paths, railway lines with different speeds applied to the segments), you could also consider an OD Matrix analysis, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419029/88814

@Babel Thank you for your answer but the plugin doesn't allow me to tag the municipality by their  respective identification codes. It just puts out a .CSV table with "start point Id" = 0 and "end point id" = random numbers and the total cost as the third column. Given this I'm not able to identify the distinct travel times between each municipality.

You speak abot OD Matrix analysis? End point id is the id of the respective entry, isn't it? So you could joint the result back to the input layer? Or what exactly do you mean?

@Babel I'm talking about the least cost path analysis tool. As input for the cost raster layer I gave each municipality its respective CSA (for the walking mode), as start point layer I selected the specific point out of the vector later containing all the municipality centroids and as end point layer I just have the complete municipality vector later. The problem is that the output for each municipality has a starting id "0", so I don't see how I can merge the CSV together to get a complete bilateral travel time matrix.

I'm not sure how the result looks like and don't have a dataset at hand to test it. Maybe, if you want to follow this specific workflow, you might post this as a separate question here. However, why do you use cost raster? don't you have a line layer you could use as a network?
